# Python pandas interpolation issues

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, interpolation

I have time series traffic data in csv format:

```
...
2015-01-04 08:29:05,271238
2015-01-04 08:34:05,329285
2015-01-04 08:39:05,-1
2015-01-04 08:44:05,260260
2015-01-04 08:49:05,263711
...
```

There's some missing data in the time series (also consecutive), plus it's not equally spaced. What I would like to do, is to use Pandas to interpolate the missing values the best I can, and then re-index the time series with 5-minutes intervals.

I am using the `interpolate()` method with `quadratic`,`slinear` and `cubic` parameters but I am not so happy with the results. I would like to try the `piecewise_polynomial` method but I get the following error:

```
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I checked my data and there's no null/zero entry. Someone claims it's a Python version issue (I am using Python 2.6), and suggests adding the following import:

```
from __future__ import division
```

but it did not work. This is the actual code:

```
values = [np.nan if x == -1 else x for x in self.y]
convertedIndex = [mktime(dateIndex.timetuple()) for dateIndex in self.x]

ts = pd.TimeSeries(values[:5000], index=self.x[:5000])
self.interpolatedValues = ts.interpolate(method='spline', order=2, downcast='infer').tolist()
```

In **self.x** you have the dates, while in **self.y** there are the time series values. I've replaced missing values (-1) with **np.nan**. I've tried using both datetime and mktime format for the dates.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks to all.

---

Here is some code which reproduces the ZeroDivisionError:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)

def random_dates(start, end, size):
    dates = [np.datetime64(date).astype('<M8[ns]').view('<i8') 
             for date in [start, end]]
    return np.random.randint(*dates, size=size).view('<M8[ns]')

N = 5
dates = np.sort(random_dates('2015-05-27 00:00:00', '2015-05-27 02:00:00', N))
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randint(100, size=N), index=dates)
ts = ts.resample('5T')

ts = ts.interpolate(method='piecewise_polynomial')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post your actual code that causes the error, also your numpy and pandas version, thanks

Comment: Yes, code please.  Also what exactly do you mean by "not so happy with the results"?  It's often helpful to explicitlye write down the exact desired results you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @riccamini: I've added some code which reproduces the ZeroDivisionError. Please check that this code accurately models your situation.

Comment: I've edited the answer with the code. I am using numpy 1.8.2 and pandas 0.16.0. @JohnE I am not satisfied because occasionally the interpolated values are huge negative numbers, and they make no sense as travel-time data.

Comment: Possibly you are fall into bug https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10365